# Magento 2.4.2 Modules won't work

Tags: magento2, module, third-party-module, routes

This is registration.php

```
<?php   

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,'Mymodule_Newmodule1', __DIR__);
```

routes.xml file is here

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="module1" frontName="module1">
            <module name="Mymodule_Newmodule1" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Here is the controller file

```
<?php

namespace Mymodules\Newmodule1\Controller\Page;


class Helloworld extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $_pageFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory
    ) {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        echo "Hello world";
        exit;
    }
}
```

When i check in browser it show 404

My base url newsite.new1
**newsite.new1/module1/page/helloworld** returns 404

Comment: are you create module.xml file ?. Please check your module successfully installed or not via following command.

php bin/magento module:status Mymodule_Newmodule1

Comment: yes i created module.xml and it its enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys i finally found solution  thank you guys for answering i appreciate your help.
The Problem is

my module is in **app/code/Mymodules/Newmodule1**
but i registered my module as **Mymodule_Newmodule1** i missed the **s**

Answer (score 0):

Try this below method.

https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-page/

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: do we need to give permission each time we create a module in linux

Comment: No.
after module created , you have to run these commands
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:flush

Answer (score 0):

Please create layout file for indentify controller url

> create module1_page_helloworld.xml

and below is my code's example

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * @category   Rajesh 
 * @package    Rajesh_Gohil
 * @author     gohilrajesh92@gmail.com
 * @copyright  Rajesh Gohil
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */
 -->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Mymodules\Newmodule1\Block\ModuleBlock" name="view.template" template="view.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

u need to also create block class and template for render layout in magento2

below is my block file

> app/code/Mymodules/Newmodule1/Block/ModuleBlock.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @category   rajesh
 * @package    rajesh_gohil
 * @author     gohilrajesh92@gmail.com
 * @copyright  rajesh gohil
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

namespace Mymodules\Newmodule1\Block;

/**
 * Purchase content block
 */
class ModuleBlock xtends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Module Title'));
        
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

create phtml file also and add your code in phtml whatever you want to show on frontend.

> app/code/Mymodules/Newmodule1/view/frontend/templates/view.phtml

```
<p>hello here</p>
```

hope this helps.